# ¿Como puedo imprimir la ubicación en leaflet obteniendo las coordenadas desde la base de datos?

Tags: nodejs, phpmyadmin, express

Estoy imprimiendo la ubicación que me da mi navegador pero ahora quiero imprimir la ubicación obteniendo las coordenadas desde la base de datos, lo estoy intentando en la parte de Controller.Ubicaion pero no tengo exitoso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

la consulta a las base de datos la realizaría mediante php.

Por otra parte, en tu archivo JavaScript obtendría dicha información mediante la función de ajax $.get().

Si no te aclaras o no consigues resolver el problema puedo hacerte un código de ejemplo.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola me ayudarías mucho si me ayudas con el ejemplo, ya que apenas estoy empezando con node y me falta aclarar muchas cosas aun, gracias de ante mano